# Deserializing JSON that contains a variable that begins with "@"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8

I am working on a Windows 8 app wherein I need to deserialize a JSON feed that contains variables which begin with an '@' sign.
I've defined classes that have members with the same names as the variables in the JSON, then call DataContractJsonSerializer to deserialize the JSON into C# classes.  This all works fine and dandy except for the variable names that begin with '@'.
Like this:

```
public class HotelDetails
{
    public string hotelId;
    public string name;
    public string address1;
...

}
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"@order":"0",
   "hotelId":268026,
   "name":"Monte Cristo",
   "address1":"600 Presidio Avenue",
...
```

Since I can't define a C# variable that begins with '@' how do I deserialize the "@order" variable?

Comment: "Since I can't define a C# variable that begins with '@'" Actually, you can define variables with `@` (try it, it's fun). It wouldn't fix your problem, though.

Comment: It's fun... but you should never do it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this?

```
[DataContract]
public class HotelDetails
{
    [DataMember(Name="@order")]
    public string order;

    [DataMember(Name="hotelId")]    
    public string hotelId;

    [DataMember(Name="name")]  
    public string name;

    [DataMember(Name="address1")]  
    public string address1;
}
```

Don't know if that works though... haven't tested it.

Comment: Almost correct, luksan; you just forgot the `Name=`, which I added.

Comment: You guys are friggin' geniuses.  Adding the DataCOntract and DataMember attributes worked.